# MS Access database not updating

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

Can anybody tell me why my database isn't updating? Here's my code:

```
protected void editSection_selected(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int index = grdPhone.SelectedIndex;
    GridViewRow row = grdPhone.Rows[index+1];
    string values = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
    int tempVal = Convert.ToInt32(values);
    int caseage = Convert.ToInt32(keyId);
    int value = tempVal;
    /*OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnstring);
    //string query = "Update Categories set HRS_LEVEL_AMOUNT=" + tempVal + " where parent_id=65 and ID=" + caseage;
    string query = "Delete HRS_LEVEL_AMOUNT from Categories where parent_id=65 and id=" + caseage;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    accPhoneNumbers.UpdateCommand = "Update Categories set HRS_LEVEL_AMOUNT=" + tempVal + " where parent_id=65 and ID=" + caseage;
    */
    string str = "UPDATE Categories SET HRS_LEVEL_AMOUNT = ? WHERE ID=?";
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnstring))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con))
        {

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HRS_LEVEL_AMOUNT", tempVal);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", caseage);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Label1.Text += " editSection Success! (B) " + tempVal;
}
```

The commented part is my first solution (including the accPhoneNumbers.UpdateCommand).
I really need your help guys.

Comment: Try to get the return value of the ExecuteNonQuery command. It should be > 0 if any record has been updated. If it is zero then the where condition fails. Also add the connection string to your code. Where is located the database and what kind of project is this (WinForms, ASP.NET ...)

Comment: Try to debug your code, step by step with F11

Comment: Do you not have the same placeholder string for replacement? "HRS_LEVEL_AMOUNT = ? WHERE ID=?""

Comment: Yes Steve. The ExecuteNonQuery is Zero. The values of the "ID" exists in the database though. Why is that?

Comment: Try substituting a know value for ID. If it works, you have a problem with ID.

Comment: Your suggestion worked Remou. But how should I put value on ID?

Comment: You need to find the value of caseage, I do not see where you are assigning a value.

Comment: I used a global variable for caseage. The value changes as the code jumps from a function to another.

Comment: You should be sure that the variable is correct at the point where you call the ExecuteNonQuery. Also, what kind of datatype field are HRS_LEVEL_AMOUNT and ID?. They should be Numeric because you pass them using AddWithValue

Comment: Yes sir, they are numeric. I think my problem is the global variable that holds caseage. It changes when the process jumps to another function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you:

```
string str = "UPDATE Categories SET HRS_LEVEL_AMOUNT = @value1 WHERE ID=@value2";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnstring))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con))
    {

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", tempVal);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", caseage);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

For more information you can visit this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQ2QjRr3toM)